# ListView is updating weirdly

Tags: android, listview

The following is my layout for a custom row in a listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Well Hello Motherfucker"
        android:id="@+id/geventProfileName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTop"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/no_picture"
        android:id="@+id/geventEventPhoto"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:alpha="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asfda"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:id="@+id/geventTitle"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Read More"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/geventReadMoreButton"
        android:background="@drawable/readtab"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/geventDescription"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/geventDetails"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        />



</FrameLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutBottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#9E9E9E"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/numberOfLikesGEvent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberOfLikesGEvent"
        android:id="@+id/likeTextViewGEvent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Like"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dislikeTextViewGEvent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/numberOfDislikesGEvent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="200"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dislikeTextViewGEvent"

        android:text="Dislike"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/photo"

    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FFF"/>
```

And this is my CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GEvent> {


boolean hasLiked;
boolean hasDisliked;
FirebaseUser fbUser;
ArrayList<String> uids;
ArrayList<String> dUids;
GEvent currentEvent;

private TextView likeTextView;
private TextView numberOfLikes;
private TextView dislikeTextView;
private TextView numberOfDislikes;
private TextView readMoreButton;
private TextView eventDetails;
private TextView titleGevent;
private ImageView eventPhoto;
private TextView profileName;
private TextView descriptionGevent;

private String description;
private String titleForGEvent;
private String detailsGEvent;
private boolean hasLoaded=true;

private de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView circleImageView;

private Context mContext;

private boolean wantsToReadMore=false;

String profilePhotoLink;


PopupWindow pw;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, GEvent[] resource) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row , resource);

    this.mContext = context;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    final  View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example,parent,false);

    final GEvent gEvent = getItem(position);

    currentEvent = gEvent;

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();



     titleGevent = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.geventTitle);
     descriptionGevent = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.geventDescription);
     profileName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.geventProfileName);
     likeTextView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.likeTextViewGEvent);
     numberOfLikes = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfLikesGEvent);
     numberOfDislikes =(TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfDislikesGEvent);
     dislikeTextView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.dislikeTextViewGEvent);
    readMoreButton = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.geventReadMoreButton);
    eventPhoto = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.geventEventPhoto);
    eventDetails = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.geventDetails);
    circleImageView = (CircleImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    description = gEvent.getDescription();
    detailsGEvent = gEvent.getgEventDate()+"\n"+gEvent.getgEventTime()+"\n"+gEvent.getVenue1()+"\n"+gEvent.getVenue2()+"\n"+gEvent.getContactEmail()+"\n"+gEvent.getContactPhoneNumber();
    titleForGEvent = gEvent.getTitle();


    if(gEvent.isHasPhoto()){

        hasLoaded= false;
        readMoreButton.setText("Loading");

    }

    readMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            if(hasLoaded) {
                Log.i("CA","Entered hasLoaded Function");
                readMoreFunction();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Loading....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });





    titleGevent.setText(gEvent.getTitle());




    String uuid = gEvent.getUuid();
    Boolean hasPhoto = gEvent.isHasPhoto();



    profileName.setText(gEvent.getProfileUsername());


    if(hasPhoto) {


        final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

        pathRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

                Bitmap picturel = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.geventEventPhoto);

                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),picturel);

                imageView.setBackground(d);

                Log.i("CA","Entered hasRetrieved Photo and update hasLoaded");

                readMoreButton.setText("Read More");

                hasLoaded=true;

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                Log.i("Error","Couldn't Download");
            }
        });

    }




    return customView;
}
```

public void readMoreFunction(){

```
    Log.i("CA","Entered readMoreFunction Function");

    if(wantsToReadMore){            //wants to read less now

        Log.i("CA","Entered Read Less Function");

        eventPhoto.setAlpha(1f);
        descriptionGevent.setText("");

        eventDetails.setText("");

        readMoreButton.setText("Read More");

        titleGevent.setText(titleForGEvent);

        wantsToReadMore=false;

    }
    else{                           //Wants to read more
        Log.i("CA","Entered Read More Function");
        eventPhoto.setAlpha(0.5f);
        descriptionGevent.setText(description);

          eventDetails.setText(detailsGEvent);

        titleGevent.setText("");

        readMoreButton.setText("Read Less");

        wantsToReadMore=true;

    }
```

So my problem is that whenever I am calling this CustomAdapter, when only one list Item is there it works perfectly, however whenever there are multiple list items, the adapter starts behaving strangely. For instance, whenever there are 2 items, If i press the " Read More " button for the first item, it triggers for the second item, even though in the logs it shows that data on which it is working is the first item itself.

If there are more than 2 items , then the above pattern is observed , i.e, whenever I click the "Read More" button of a given item, it triggers for the next item in the listview. Sometimes it is just stuck on "Loading " even after the image has loaded or the "Read More" button doesn't even respond.[image]
[image: In this the Button isn't working]
I have been banging my head for the past two days , looking for the bug. Hope you guys can help me.Thanks in Advance.

PS:- The "Load More" Button is out of place, excuse me for that.

Comment: You need to save the state of each item(if read more has been click or not) inside your model, `GEvent`. Also the `readMoreFunction` method is using stale data. It will always have the value of the last iteration of `getView`.

Comment: How may I use the current data and prevent stale data in the getView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `GEvent` class create a `boolean` field,

```
class GEvent {
    private boolean readMoreClicked;

    public boolean isReadMoreClicked(){
        return readMoreClicked;
    }

    public void setReadMoreClicked(boolean readMoreClicked){
        this.readMoreClicked = readMoreClicked;
    }
}
```

Inside `getView`,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ....

    if(gEvent.isReadMoreClicked()) {
        Log.i("CA","Entered More Less Function");
        ...
    } else {
        Log.i("CA","Entered Less More Function");
        ...
    }

    readMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(hasLoaded) {
                Log.i("CA","Entered hasLoaded Function");

                // user has clicked Read More. Save the state
                gEvent.setReadMoreClicked(!gEvent.isReadMoreClicked());
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Loading....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

It may need some editing. But I hope you get the idea. :)

Comment: Life saver. Thank you .